# Change pixels of a 2 bit image; How can I extend 3-color palette image to have a 4th palette entry?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a 2-bit image, which has pixels as 0,1 and 2. Where 0 is the background and 1 and 2 are labels. I want to create one more label by changing some pixels to 3. I tried imageJ fill with a colour picker, but it's only letting me choose from existing labels.
I tried using Python as well as Matlab but everything is reading the image as 8-bit and saving as 8-bit. Is there any way to do it using any program or code?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"image_1.png")
# cv2.imshow('image',img)

box =[20,1796,2492,1915]

img[box[1]:box[1]+box[3],box[0]:box[0]+box[2]] = 3
cv2.imwrite(r"image_1_label.png",img)
```

Comment: Please share your 2-bit image - use something that will not modify it, e.g. Google Drive, Dropbox, github.

Comment: OpenCV can only write PNGs with 1, 8 or 16 bits per pixel ([source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_png.cpp#L422).

Comment: look at PIL. it can deal with palettes.

Comment: Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick can handle 2-bit images.

Comment: Just because an image is saved as 8 bit doesn't mean you can't just ignore 6 of them.  The compression used by PNG means there will be negligible waste from those extra 6 bits.